# 404 Error while deploying mirror counter example

Tags: google-mirror-api

I am trying to modify the [Counter Mirror Example](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-counter-sample-python) and get it running from my computer.
Instead of just incrementing by 1, I'd like to increment by 10 (trivial, yes but the goal is to get it running) so I changed the the necessary line in handler.py (in /notify) to:

```
'increment': lambda num: num + 10,
```

As for the basic glassware setting up:

In the API console I added the counteraugmented.appspot dot com/oauthcallback and localhost/oauthcallback (i cant post localhost or >2 links, sorry)

Glass API is turned on.

Updated client_secret.json with the id, secret and redirect uri's. Triple checked spelling and all instances included https, not http 
Updated app.yaml with application name. 
ran:
 `./appcfg --oauth2 update counteraugmented/`
output:

```
08:43 PM Host: appengine.google.com
08:43 PM Application: counteraugmented; version: 1
08:43 PM 
Starting update of app: counteraugmented, version: 1
08:43 PM Getting current resource limits.
08:43 PM Scanning files on local disk.
08:43 PM Cloning 13 static files.
08:43 PM Cloning 60 application files.
08:43 PM Compilation starting.
08:43 PM Compilation completed.
08:43 PM Starting deployment.
08:43 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:43 PM Deployment successful.
08:43 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
08:44 PM Completed update of app: counteraugmented, version: 1
```

Went to https://counteraugmented.appspot.com/oauth2callback and got a 404 error. 
In the API console log:

```
2013-08-06 20:53:50.500 /oauth2callback 404 14ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
70.166.86.68 - - [06/Aug/2013:20:53:50 -0700] "GET /oauth2callback HTTP/1.1" 404 188 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36" "counteraugmented.appspot.com" ms=15 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000021 app_engine_release=1.8.3 instance=00c61b117c0e4f53bedaf5e84288859a16dd0b9e
```

I successfully got the python quickstart example running, this is my next hurdle. 
Any suggestions on how I can go about remedying this would be greatly appreciated. (Obviously new to oauth, stackoverflow and glassdev). Thanks!

Comment: I see "Hello world!" when I visit https://counteraugmented.appspot.com. Where/what is the file that is generating this Hello World?

Comment: I redeployed using GAE v3 and it is working. Previously I was using the GAE mac app on a different computer. Not a satisfactory answer though, I will dig around and see what the real difference is. counteraugmented.appspot.com should now to render the oauth page, acceptance and initialization should push a counter that augments by 10 on Glass.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I encourage you to answer this Stack Overflow question when you find a satisfactory answer so that others may benefit.